# How to use PL/pgSQL to transform an original table to desired two tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Say we have this table things_happened with schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE things_happened
(
  zipcode character varying(10),
  city character varying(50),
  state character varying(2),
  metro character varying(50),
  countyname character varying(50),
  "1996-04" integer,
  "1996-05" integer,
  "1996-06" integer,
  "1996-07" integer,
  "1996-08" integer,
  "1996-09" integer,
  ...
  "2014-09" integer,
  "2014-10" integer,
  "2014-11" integer
)
```

It looks funny because the data is imported from csv files by other folks.

It's obvious that this table is not efficient, the values of lots of months are empty for a particular area. So I was thinking creating two tables out of it.

The schemas of desired two tables are:

```
area_info (zipcode, city, state, metro, countyname) with zipcode as primary key
things_happened_per_month (year, month, zipcode, times) with year, month, zipcode as primary key
```

Because the size of the table is big and the data keeps coming and the column name has to become a parameter, I was wondering how to use "PL/pgSQL - SQL Procedural Language" to do it? Or any other efficient solution?

Comment: This is indeed possible and not too hard, but can you explain "data keeps coming"? You mean more inserts on table things_happened? more csv files? data coming in other format? does things_happened already exist and have data?

Comment: more csv files I think. yes things_happened already exist and have data and I would like to translate things_happened to area_info (zipcode, city, state, metro, countyname) and 
things_happened_per_month (year, month, zipcode, times). I have problems dealing with the column name like "2014-11", how to translate a column name to an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table things_happened looks like a pivot table and you want to normalize that to a more efficient data structure. You will have to write a PlPgSQL function to do that.

Since you have many months, and possibly more columns added for later months, I suggest you dynamically determine the month columns in the table and then loop over the results. In the example below I assume that you have already copied the area_info data into its own table; I focus here on the "times" column in the thpm table (which I assume you have already created).

### Dynamic solution

The below function uses a dynamic look-up of the YYYY-DD columns in the table and then loops over records and columns to get the data into the normalized table. (Many thanks to Pavel Stehule for pointing out the last finicky error in the code.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_things_happened() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  col_names text[];
  period    text;
  th        things_happened%rowtype;
  times     integer;
BEGIN
  -- Get the currently present columns from the catalog
  SELECT array_agg(attname::text) INTO col_names
  FROM pg_attribute att
  JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = att.attrelid
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  WHERE c.relname = 'things_happened'
    AND n.nspname = 'public'
    AND position('-' in attname) = 5; -- only "times" columns

  -- Loop over all the rows in the things_happened table
  FOR th IN SELECT * FROM things_happened LOOP
    -- Now loop over column names
    FOREACH period IN ARRAY col_names LOOP
      -- Fudge the proper column from the th record into a local variable
      EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || quote_ident(period) INTO times USING th;

      -- If times is a proper value, insert it into the thpm table
      IF times IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO things_happened_per_month (year, month, zipcode, times) VALUES
          (substring(period from 1 for 4)::int, substring(period from 6 for 2)::int, th.zipcode, times);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This should work as a one-off exercise. If the original table keeps on getting new data, you should run this function periodically and then do an `UPSERT` in the innermost `EXECUTE`: first try to do an `UPDATE` of the "times" value, if that fails because there is no data for the year, month, zipcode combination, then do an `INSERT`. See many other questions here on SO for examples.

### Static solution

The below function is the non-dynamic variant. You will have to put separate blocks of code for every month in the things_happened table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_things_happened() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  th        things_happened%rowtype;
  times     integer;
BEGIN
  -- Loop over all the rows in the things_happened table
  FOR th IN SELECT * FROM things_happened LOOP
    -- Copy the below block for 1996, April, for all other months.
    SELECT th."1996-04" INTO times;
    IF times IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO things_happened_per_month (year, month, zipcode, times) VALUES (1996, 4, th.zipcode, times);
    -- 1996, May
    SELECT th."1996-05" INTO times;
    IF times IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO things_happened_per_month (year, month, zipcode, times) VALUES (1996, 5, th.zipcode, times);
    END IF;
    -- Etc.
  END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Ugly, but functional.

Comment: This is gonna be silly. This seams to create a function but how to run this function?

Comment: I used SELECT normalize_things_happened(); is there any direct way to do it?

Comment: And I am still confused that is there any parameter I need to fill in in your code?

Comment: And there is an error msg when I run it: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "th"
LINE 1: SELECT th."1996-04"
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT th."1996-04"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function normalize_things_happened() line 22 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "th"
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function normalize_things_happened() line 22 at EXECUTE statement

Comment: This is not silly at all. You asked for a PL/PgSQL solution and then you get a function by definition; there is no other option. You indeed call the function through a `SELECT` statement, without any parameters; that is the direct way to do it. There was indeed an error: the `th` local variable needs to be of a specified rowtype instead of the generic `RECORD` type; see updated answer (`DECLARE` section).

Comment: I changed the type of th to "things_happened%rowtype;" but it's still the same error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "th"
LINE 1: SELECT th."1996-04"
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT th."1996-04"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function normalize_things_happened() line 22 at EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "th"
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function normalize_things_happened() line 22 at EXECUTE statement

Comment: This appears to be a bug. See updated answer with a functional but ugly solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts! Your solution works great! However it seems to check every "year-month" column and every row to see if it's NOT NULL and INSERT it. I was thinking can we just check every "year-month" column and use things like this to insert the whole columns at once: INSERT INTO things_happened_per_month
(
SELECT zipcode, 1996 AS year, 4 AS month, "1996-04" AS times
FROM org WHERE "1996-04" IS NOT NULL
)

Comment: That is possible indeed, but not efficient because you have to query your entire (large) table for every month. But if the new data comes in as new month columns only then that would be a neat solution. Any new zipcodes would not have their old data added, though.

Comment: @Patrick: you cannot to use plpgsql variable inside dynamic statement directly. Dynamic statements are defined in own namespace. So using EXECUTE 'SELECT plpgsql_var' is wrong. You should to use parameter placeholder and clause USING.

Comment: @PavelStehule: So what would the offending statement look like?

Comment: @PavelStehule: Got your answer from pgsql-bugs. That easy huh? How come I didn't think of that myself? Answer updated.

Comment: @Patrick: Dynamic SQL is specific - not hard, but not trivial. And I implemented a USING clause to EXECUTE statement, so I am well trained in this case.